# Can I use rpy2 to save a pandas dataframe to an .Rdata file?

Tags: python, r, pandas

I never used rpy2 before, but I am just wondering if I could use it to save a python object (a pandas DataFrame) in an R-readable file. I am having trouble to move objects between these environments mainly because I'm using Windows and the data source is an Excel file. Yes, the kind that has cells with text including inverted commas, newlines, and all the stuff that CSV can't handle adequately.

I usually rely on XLConnectJars, but it seems to be broken

```
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Program Files/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.csiro.au/bin/windows/contrib/2.15/XLConnectJars_0.2-4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 16538311 bytes (15.8 Mb)
opened URL
downloaded 15.3 Mb

Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 16011264 != reported length 16538311
```

pandas reads it properly, but I need to use the information in R.

Comment: The warning is not an error. The package will quite probably still work (I have had this warning intermittently without any actual problems)

Comment: @mnel Failed with error:  ‘package ‘XLConnectJars’ 0.2-0 was found, but == 0.2.4 is required by ‘XLConnect’’

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use rpy2 to do this. Once you have the data in a panda, you have to transmit it to R. [This link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/r_interface.html) provides an experimental interface between Python Pandas and R data.frames. A code example copied from the website:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas.rpy.common as com

df = DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C':[7,8,9]},
                index=["one", "two", "three"])
r_dataframe = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(df)

print type(r_dataframe)
 <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.DataFrame'>

print r_dataframe
      A B C
one   1 4 7
two   2 5 8
three 3 6 9
```

Comment: So how would you write this `data.frame` to an `.RData` file?

Comment: Using the `save` function.

Comment: From the Panda documentation:
`Up to pandas 0.19, a pandas.rpy module existed with functionality to convert between pandas and rpy2 objects. This functionality now lives in the rpy2 project itself. See the updating section of the previous documentation for a guide to port your code from the removed pandas.rpy to rpy2 functions.`

Comment: This option seems to be not available anymore

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you write/read `.RData` files with `rpy2` (since accepted solution is deprecated and doesn't show how to save to `.RData` file):

```
import rpy2
from rpy2 import robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

# read .RData file as a pandas dataframe
def load_rdata_file(filename):
    r_data = robjects.r['get'](robjects.r['load'](filename))
    df = pandas2ri.ri2py(r_data)
    return df

# write pandas dataframe to an .RData file
def save_rdata_file(df, filename):
    r_data = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)
    robjects.r.assign("my_df", r_data)
    robjects.r("save(my_df, file='{}')".format(filename))
```

Comment: I am trying to write a pandas df to an rda file.  I followed this process but for some reason, it adds columns.  My original df has 92 columns, when I open it in R, it has 1942 columns.  They are created from values of another column (ie if a col name is A, the I have A.1, A.2, A.3, etc filled with a single value from the original A column).  Open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Using the most recent version of `rpy2`, version 3.3.2, I was unable to get the other answers to work. It appears that conversion works a bit differently now.

```py
import pandas
p_df = pandas.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
```

The following code will convert the above pandas dataframe to an R dataframe and save the R dataframe as an R `.rds` file.

```py
from rpy2 import robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter

# Convert pandas dataframe to R dataframe
with localconverter(robjects.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    r_df = robjects.conversion.py2rpy(p_df)

# Save R dataframe as .rds file
r_file = "file.rds"
robjects.r.assign("my_df_tosave", r_df)
robjects.r(f"saveRDS(my_df_tosave, file='{r_file}')")
```

The following code will load the `.rds` file and convert it back to a pandas dataframe.

```py
# Load as R dataframe from .rds file
r_file = "file.rds"
robjects.r(f"df_to_load <- readRDS('{r_file}')") 
r_df = robjects.r["df_to_load"]

# Convert R dataframe to pandas dataframe
with localconverter(robjects.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    p_df = robjects.conversion.rpy2py(r_df)
```

Comment: Any idea on how I could add a path to ```r_file``` when saving? I get the following error when I add one: ```ParsingError: Parsing status not OK - PARSING_STATUS.PARSE_NULL```. Works fine otherwise!!

Comment: To add a path when saving you can do `r_file=myfolder/file.rds`. @Jossy I just tested this and it works for me - do you have a minimal working example showing the error message that you are getting?

Comment: Hey. Thanks for replying. ```r_file = r"C:\Users\Philip\test2.rds"```. Same code as yours. Works fine with just a file name. Adding a path gives the ```PARSING``` error...

Comment: Just tested ```r_file = "C:/Users/Philip/test2.rds"``` and it works fine! Thanks for pushing me to test a little more.