# Is there a way to store a pandas data frame in R format?

Tags: python, r, csv, pandas

R has its own format that is significantly more expressive than csv (knows about factors, for example). The extension is usually .Rdata, and it is manipulated from R using the `load` and `save` functions.

I was wondering if the python pandas library know about this format? If not, is there another format (better than csv) for exchange between pandas and R?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use rpy2 to save a pandas dataframe to an .Rdata file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081858/can-i-use-rpy2-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-to-an-rdata-file)

Comment: @Carsten : I don't care about using rpy2 in particular, so my question is more general.

Comment: I don't know which information rpy2 will read from/write to the .Rdata file. Otherwise, both R and pandas support Stata files ([R](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/read.dta.html), [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-stata-writer)), hdf5 ([R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h5r/h5r.pdf), [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-hdf5)) or a SQL database.

Comment: @Carsten : plus rpy2 seems rather heavy weighted since it calls R directly, so a more direct solution would be better.

Comment: Yeah it's not great, but it's the only way I know how to do that. I've retracted the close vote but will leave my comment for reference, since using rpy2 _is_ a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: @Carsten: fair enough, I actually think your comment should be an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to think for the longest time that you needed an R instance to deserialize R objects -- and loading a saved R object, or set of objects, amount to reading a (binary, likely compressed) data stream and de-serializing it.

But Davor proved me wrong. An existence proof is provided in his [CPAN module Statistics-R-IO](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Statistics-R-IO/) which does this in Perl. *Presumably* someone with enough motivation could abstract this into C library which many other projects, including Python, could load. Or use to save Pandas data for R.

Having a better data exchange would be nice.  Otherwise, you can of course use language-agnostic interchange formats such as [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).

(Note: CPAN.org seems to be down/slow right now. Use Google Cache if need be.)