# python dataframe write to R data format

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I  have a question with writing a dataframe format to R.

I have 1000 column X 77 row data. I want to write this dataframe to R data.

When I use function of

```
r_dataframe = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(df)
```

it gives me an error like dataframe object has no arttribute type.

When I see the code of com.convert_to_r_dataframe(). it just get the column of dataframe, and get the colunm.dtype.type. 
In this moment, the column is dataframe, I think large columns dataframe has inside dataframes?
Any one have some idea to solve this problem?

Comment: The `feather`-Package might help: https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/29/feather/

It is a format that both, Python and R can read

Comment: @Floo0 Thank you for your comment. but, I can not modify the R data server. I can only use python to save as R.

Comment: Feather does not currently support sparse dataframes either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The data.frame transfer from Python to R could be accomplished with the feather format. Via [this link](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/29/feather/) you can find more information.

Quick example.

Export in Python:

```
import feather
path = 'my_data.feather'
feather.write_dataframe(df, path)
```

Import in R:

```
library(feather)
path <- "my_data.feather"
df <- read_feather(path)
```

In this case you'll have the data in R as a data.frame. You can then decide to write it to an RData file.

```
save(df, file = 'my_data.RData')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. but I don't think this is the best way to impalement.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'feather' has no attribute 'write_dataframe'

Comment: pip install feather-format # resolved above AttributeError message

Answer (score 4):

simplest, bestest practical solution is to export in `csv`

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe.to_csv('mypath/file.csv')
```

and then read in R using `read.csv`

Comment: The python output must be Rdata. I just save dataframe to csv and read it  using pd.read_csv(), but it also have the same problem.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081858/can-i-use-rpy2-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-to-an-rdata-file

Comment: There are many good reasons why this is not the "simplest, bestest", but if you're going to make a superlative claim, be prepared to prove. it.  `to_csv` can be quite slow, but more importantly, there is value not always having to divert to CSV, just to reimport it elsewhere from CSV.  It can be helpful to have a more direct route to your destination.

Comment: Doesn't answer OP