# Convert Pandas df to rda file

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2, rda

I am cleaning my data in Python, but the program we use for visualizations is set up for R.  I am trying to save my dataframes as rda files.  I was able to find resources on here to get started, however my df has 92 columns, when it converts to rda, it has 1942 columns, it's similar to the following.

```
import rpy2
from rpy2 import robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B':[10, 9, 8], 'C':['A', 'B', 'C']})


    A   B   C
0   1   10  A
1   2   9   B
2   3   8   C
```

EDIT: I have tried both these conversions and got the same result with both.

```
df = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)
```

AND

```
def save_rdata_file(df, filename):
    r_data = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)
    robjects.r.assign('my_df', r_data)
    robjects.r("save(my_df, file=paste0('{}'))".format(filename))

save_rdata_file(df, file_location)



result = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B':[10, 9, 8], 'C':['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'A.1': [1, 1, 1], 'A.2': [2, 2, 2], 'A.3':[3, 3, 3],
                   'B.1':[10, 10, 10], 'B.2':[9, 9, 9], 'B.3':[8, 8, 8],
                   'C.1':['A', 'A', 'A'], 'C.2':['B', 'B', 'B'], 'C.3':['C', 'C', 'C']})

    A   B   C   A.1 A.2 A.3 B.1 B.2 B.3 C.1 C.2 C.3
0   1   10  A   1   2   3   10  9   8   A   B   C
1   2   9   B   1   2   3   10  9   8   A   B   C
2   3   8   C   1   2   3   10  9   8   A   B   C
```

Comment: I'd advise saving them as feather files.  Then from R, open the feather files directly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your undesired results. Please post: `print(rpy2.__version__)`. And since [rpy2](https://rpy2.bitbucket.io/) is an actively developed project, be sure to be using latest version.

Comment: By the way, .rdata is usually for environments allows more than one object to save to disk and hence is overfkill for one data frame. Consider .rds which is only **one** specific object saved to disk.

Comment: @Parfait I have a total of 6 dfs I am trying to save in an rda file.  I am using version 2.9.4 of rpy2.

Comment: Actually what is *result*? How are you generating it? Please show that line. FYI - make sure all posted code is runnable.

Comment: @Parfait the result is what I was seeing when I opened it up in R, after running the code above in Python.  There were 2 columns that were type 'object' that this was happening to, I changed them to type 'str' and it worked fine.  Not sure why it was only those cols though, there were other objects in the df.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were using [@anthonybell's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081858/can-i-use-rpy2-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-to-an-rdata-file):

```
import rpy2
from rpy2 import robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
import pandas as pd
pandas2ri.activate()

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B':[10, 9, 8], 'C':['A', 'B', 'C']})
r_data = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)
robjects.r.assign("df", r_data)
robjects.r("save(df, file='test.rda')")

In R:
load("test.rda")
> ls()
[1] "df"
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: int  1 2 3
 $ B: int  10 9 8
 $ C: chr  "A" "B" "C"
```

It works quite ok for me. I am on R 3.6.1, python 3.6.10, pandas 1.0.1, rpy 2.9.4. So below is another solution, using pickle, but it requires using reticulate in R:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B':[10, 9, 8], 'C':['A', 'B', 'C']})
df.to_pickle("./test.pkl")

In R:
library(reticulate)
pd = import("pandas",convert=TRUE)
str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: num  1 2 3
 $ B: num  10 9 8
 $ C: chr  "A" "B" "C"
 - attr(*, "pandas.index")=RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
```